# Applying an operation to each vector from 2d numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need it for 2d arrays but would also be interested in higher dimensions.
If I have two numpy 2DArrays lets say A and B and a function f which takes 2 vectors and puts out a scalar. Performance is important and numpy array operations are really fast so how do I get the matrix:

```
(f(a1,b1),f(a1, b2)...)
(f(a2,b1), f(a2,b2)...)
(...                  )
```

a(i) and b(i) being 1d arrays/vectors

By applying something like f(A,B) and without using any loops.

With some methods I can use the axis=1 but how do I define my own function like that or is there an other way?

Comment: It's hard help you with an unspecified `f(a,b)`.  Basically you need to identify the steps inside `f` that only work with 1d arrays, and try to replace them with ones the work with many such arrays at once, the whole `A`.  That requires familiarity with the basic `numpy` operations - the fast ones that operate on whole arrays.  There's no short cut to learning the core of `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj f could simply be the dot product of both vectors as used in the normal matrix multiplication already given, i thought maybe there is a way to do this with any Bilinear form or Norm, and get a new matrix with all the combinations of the vectors from A and B.

Comment: `np.einsum` is a good tool for applying matrix multiplication to higher dimensional arrays.   It's modeled on the Einstein notation most commonly used in physics: `sum(for k) (A_ijk * B_ikl` etc.  `matmu` (the `@` operator) is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and most efficient, solution is to use a for loop. np.vectorize won't help you here, because it passes scalars to a function.

Assuming your arrays have two columns:

```
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    print(f(a[0],b[0]))
    print(f(a[1],b[1]))
```

would print the values of f that you would want to return.